# How do I access parameters returned in a redirect uri?

Tags: python, python-requests, spotify

I'm using the requests library in python to follow [this guide](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/tutorials/code-flow) and it mentions accessing a code from the redirected uri. The problem is, after spotify asks for permission and redirects, I can't access that new uri. I can't find any information on accessing this data. Most places are either different languages or are using flask, which I don't think is relevant here.

Here's what I've tried:

```
    def getPermissions(self):
        params = {
            "response_type": "code",
            "client_id": self._CLIENT_ID,
            "scope": self.SCOPE,
            "redirect_uri": "https://youtube.com",
            "state": self.getRandomString(),
            "show_dialog": "false"
        }
        self.mostRecentResponse = requests.get(self.AUTH_URL, params=params)
        webbrowser.open(self.mostRecentResponse.url)
```

`self.mostRecentResponse` doesn't update after i get redirected, and so I'm not sure how to find the URI.

the URI is meant to have details attached to it by Spotify, like this: "https://my-domain.com/callback?code=NApCCg..BkWtQ&state=34fFs29kd09". Instead, I just get the previous URI. Its the "code=xyz" that I'm trying to access.

Is there another way i should handle that user permission, other than by using webbrowser?

Comment: "*[...] are using flask, which I don't think is relevant here*" How did you come to that conclusion? Spotify pushing the user's browser to the redirect URI triggers a `GET` request, and generally that request should be captured by an HTTP server listening at the redirect URI. Flask is but one framework you could use to accomplish such a task. This is a pretty standard way to fulfill a foundational component of an Oauth flow, and having a `redirect_uri` of `https://youtube.com` shows me that you have a fundamental misunderstanding of what is actually happening here.

Comment: Okay that makes more sense. Just to clarify, i set youtube.com so that I could see whether the redirect uri was changing. Where could i go to find out more about these listening servers?